# co_await a C++/WinRT event

Tags: c++-winrt, cppwinrt

I would like to `co_await` the file completed event from the WinRT `AudioGraph` API.

Is this possible? It seams like a far superior way to program than using state or recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You `co_await` the `resume_on_signal` function.

```cpp
co_await winrt::resume_on_signal(m_event_handle);
```

Here's the handle being created

```cpp
HANDLE m_event_handle;
m_event_handle  = CreateEventA(nullptr, false, false, nullptr);
```

Then subscribe to the event with the following event handler

```cpp
fileInputNode.FileCompleted([this](auto, auto) { winrt::check_bool(SetEvent(m_event_handle)); });
```